# Can I use contentScaleFactor to save memory safely?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiview, uikit

I have an app that part of it is to display a grid of images.
Each ImageView is 200x150, but the images themselves are 1024x768.
If I'll try to just set those images, soon I'll get memory warnings and probably even get killed.

For the other hand if resizing those images in code is very CPU costly and take way to much time.

Now, I watched in one of the "Apple WWDC" session's video, and the guy there mentioned the contentScaleFactor of UIView that is responsible for the amount of actual bitmap memory allocated to display the view.

In the documentation they only mention cases of scale factor larger than one, but I care about setting it to a value less than one:

```
// Make sure not to divide by zero
if (image.size.width > 0 && image.size.height > 0)
{
    CGFloat widthRatio = self.imageView.frame.size.width / image.size.width;
    CGFloat heightRatio = self.imageView.frame.size.height / image.size.height;
    CGFloat aspectFitRatio = MAX(widthRatio, heightRatio);
    aspectFitRatio = MIN(1, aspectFitRatio);
    [self.imageView setContentScaleFactor:aspectFitRatio];
}
```

In this way my imageView will allocate much less memory.

My question is - Am I right? 
will it really save memory? 
Is it even "legal" to set the contentScaleFactor to < 1 values?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that won't help *much*. The thing is, `UIView` retains an image, whatever its size is. So as long as the view exists, the image occupies RAM. `contentScaleFactor` doesn't change this fact. In order to actually reduce memory footprint, you have to resample images before assigning them to a `UIView`.

However, `contentScaleFactor` does affect the size of the backing store used for rendering. Given that at this moment there are only two categories of iOS devices, and those devices use either `1.0` or `2.0` scale factor, you can simply force `contentScaleFactor` to be `1.0` on Retina devices. Note that it won't do anything for other devices.

Comment: The image object is not that big. It is the backing store for rendering that eats the memory. For example, jpg image with size of 1024x768 takes something like 300kb. This is because the jpg format is compressed. but when you want to display this image, each pixel have to be represented in its own byte (at least) so the memory required to render this image will be 1024x768 = 786kb. So reducing the backing store memory footprint should have a noticeable effect on total memory footprint

Comment: @Avrahamshuk The big question (and it is considered an implementation _detail_) is _when_ the image is decompressed. If it is decompressed each time it needs to be rendered, then it consumes little memory, but is very expensive to redraw. If it is decompressed when read from disk, then the opposite is true. I think the current implementation involves lazy loading (decompressing the image when it is drawn for the first time) and keeping the decompressed image in RAM for faster redrawing. However, I may be wrong, and that may change in any iOS release.

Comment: Your assumption make sense. So if I can assure that the contentScaleFactor is set before the image is first drawn, I'll save a bunch of memory. But I still can't accept your answer though... Now I'll go looking deeper into the drawing process of UIKit.

Comment: @Avrahamshuk No problem. Anyway, I think the question deserves a couple of sessions with Instruments.